# how to make rails 3.0 default on mac?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Here are my gems when I type in gem list in the terminal:

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

abstract (1.0.0)
actionmailer (3.0.10)
actionpack (3.0.10)
activemodel (3.0.10)
activerecord (3.0.10)
activeresource (3.0.10)
activesupport (3.0.10)
arel (2.0.10)
builder (2.1.2)
bundler (1.0.18)
erubis (2.6.6)
i18n (0.5.0)
mail (2.2.19)
mime-types (1.16)
minitest (1.6.0)
mysql2 (0.3.7)
polyglot (0.3.2)
rack (1.2.3)
rack-mount (0.6.14)
rack-test (0.5.7)
**rails (3.0.10)**
railties (3.0.10)
rake (0.8.7)
rdoc (3.9.3, 2.5.8)
rubygems-update (1.8.9)
thor (0.14.6)
treetop (1.4.10)
tzinfo (0.3.29)

Ruby -v: ruby 1.9.2

How come when I type rails -v it gives me: Rails 1.2.6? I need the 3.0 to be the default.

Answer (score 0):

Try running:

> > gem uninstall rails -v 1.2.6

and see if that works.  You can also look into RVM there is a RailsCast http://railscasts.com/episodes/200-rails-3-beta-and-rvm

It also may be necissary to use *sudo* on a mac like so:

> > sudo gem uninstall rails

Comment: it said ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::InstallError)
    gem "rails" is not installed

Comment: @Alex try running `gem uninstall rails` without version to get rid of everything.  If that doesn't work find ruby and uninstall then find where ruby was installed and delete the entire folder then reinstall.

Comment: Removing rails
Successfully uninstalled rails-3.0.10
 but not 1.2.6

Comment: Run it again `gem uninstall rails` then run `rails -v` see if it is still there.  If it is not try running `gem install rails` you also may need to try running `sudo gem uninstall rails` as it may have been installed with sudo.

Comment: @Alex make sure you're not using two versions of ruby if not try manually deleting rails by finding a file somewhat like `Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-3.0.9` and deleting it.  I cannot give the exact path as mine is on Windows.

Comment: @Alex also the Gemfile for your Rails 3 app should make it automatically go to Rails 3 when you boot the server